# How do I focus an input with Cycle.js and RxJS?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, focus, rxjs, cyclejs

How do I focus an input with Cycle? Do I need to reach inside the DOM and call `.focus()` either with or without jQuery, or is there some other way with Cycle/RxJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you do need to reach inside the DOM and call `.focus()` either with or without jQuery. However this is a **side-effect** and it is Cycle.js convention to move these kinds of side effects to a so-called **[driver](http://cycle.js.org/drivers.html)**.

The two questions the driver needs to know are:

- *which element* do you want to focus?
- *when* do you want to focus the element?

The answer to both questions can be provided by a **single stream of DOM elements**.

### Create the driver

First make your driver. Let's call it `SetFocus`. We'll make it a so-called **read-only driver**. It will read from the app's sinks but it will not provide a source to the app. Because it is *reading*, the driver's function will need to accept a formal parameter that will be a stream, call it `elem$`:

```
function makeSetFocusDriver() {
  function SetFocusDriver(elem$) {
    elem$.subscribe(elem => {
      elem.focus();
    });
  }
  return SetFocusDriver;
}
```

This driver takes whatever DOM element arrives in the stream and calls `.focus()` on it.

### Use the Driver

Add it to the list of drivers provided to the `Cycle.run` function:

```
Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
  SetFocus: makeSetFocusDriver() // add a driver
});
```

Then in your main function:

```
function main({DOM}) {

  // setup some code to produce the elem$ stream
  // that will be read by the driver ...
  // [1]: say _when_ we want to focus, perhaps we need to focus when
  //      the user clicked somewhere, or maybe when some model value
  //      has changed
  // [2]: say _what_ we want to focus
  //      provide the textbox dom element as actual value to the stream
  //      the result is:
  //      |----o-----o-----o--->
  //      where each o indicates we want to focus the textfield
  //      with the class 'field'
  const textbox$ = DOM.select('.field').observable.flatMap(x => x); // [2]
  const focusNeeded = [
    clickingSomewhere$,    // [1]
    someKindofStateChange$ // [1]
  ];
  const focus$ = Observable.merge(...focusNeeded)
    .withLatestFrom(textbox$, (_, textbox) => textbox); // [2]

  // ...

  // [*]: Add driver to sinks, the driver reads from sinks.
  //      Cycle.js will call your driver function with the parameter
  //      `elem$` being supplied with the argument of `focus$`
  return {
    DOM: vtree$,
    SetFocus: focus$, // [*]
  };
}
```

You can then configure `focusNeeded` to say when you want `.field` to be focused.

Comment: Good answer. Minor grammatical error (two/to), which I'd have edited except that edits have to be at least six characters.

Comment: Thanks @MattBurnell - I've made the edit to fix the error ("two" replaced with "to").

Answer (score 5):

You can tailor for your own situation, but this should illustrate how to solve your problem.  Let's assume you have a text input and a button.  When the button is clicked, you want the focus to remain on the text input.

First write the intent() function:

```
function intent(DOMSource) {
    const textStream$ = DOMSource.select('#input-msg').events('keyup').map(e => e.target);
    const buttonClick$ = DOMSource.select('#send-btn').events('click').map(e => e.target);

    return buttonClick$.withLatestFrom(textStream$, (buttonClick, textStream) => {
        return textStream;
    });
}
```

Then the main which has a sink to handle the lost focus side effect

```
function main(sources) {
    const textStream$ = intent(sources.DOM);

    const sink = {
       DOM: view(sources.DOM),
       EffectLostFocus: textStream$,
    }

    return sink;
}
```

Then the driver to handle this side effect would look something like

```
Cycle.run(main, {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
    EffectLostFocus: function(textStream$) {    
         textStream$.subscribe((textStream) => {
         console.log(textStream.value);
         textStream.focus();
         textStream.value = '';
      })
    }
});
```

The entire example is in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/kevinle/pen/zrJNVx).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example, written by Mr. Staltz himself: https://github.com/cyclejs/cycle-examples/blob/master/autocomplete-search/src/main.js#L298

Comment: Yeah, don't be afraid to write your own small drivers to handling things. They're really very simple functions where you isolate effects.